# Как прервать sleep_for соседнего потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++14

В приложении создаётся второй поток в котором вызывается конструкция `std::this_thread::sleep_for( … )`. 
Можно ли как то прервать этот `sleep_for` из другого потока имея экземпляр `std::thread`? Я понимаю что можно сделать флаг, запустить в цикле `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1))` и на каждой итерации проверять флаг, но в моём случае большой оверхэд недопустим. И ещё если кто знает, можно ли как-то вызвать sleep_for соседнего потока?

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::mutex mut{};

void Foo1() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (mut);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
}

void main() {
    cout << "---- point 1 ----" << endl;
    std::thread th1(Foo1);
    // Вот тут надо прервать текущий sleep_for в th1.
    th1.join();
    cout << "---- point 2 ----" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Не прерывать, не вызывать sleep в другом потоке нельзя. А вообще тут явно ощущается наличие проблемы XY. Зачем там прерывать / вызывать sleep? Может более уместно будет использование `condition_variable`?

Comment: @VTT да, вы правы. Мне был нужен condition_variable =). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем как сказал @VTT выше, тут необходимо применить std::condition_variable и вместо sleep_for использовать wait_for. Вот так изменится код примера:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable condition;
void Foo1() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    condition.wait_for(lock,std::chrono::seconds(10)); // Блокирует поток на 1 секунду либо до срабатывания condition.notify_one().
}

void main() {
    cout << "---- point 1 ----" << endl;
    std::thread th1(Foo1);
    condition.notify_one(); //Прерываем condition.wait_for в th1.
    th1.join();
    cout << "---- point 2 ----" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```